# Can rsync have user-specific read-write permissions?

Tags: windows, permissions, rsync

I'm looking into using rsync to publish a project I'm working on.  However, I'm running into one issue--I need to make it publicly readable, but not publicly writable (I'd rather not have someone inject something malicious and have it uploaded to anyone who tries to get updates).  I'd like to use rsync to upload any changes as well, but I can't figure out how to restrict write access to a given user.  Is this possible?

I'll be using a windows server, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The man page for rsyncd.conf lists some of the options you can use with the rsync daemon, which include:

```
read only
              This parameter determines whether clients will be able to upload files or
              not.  If  "read  only"  is  true then any attempted uploads will fail. If
              "read only" is false then uploads will be possible if file permissions on
              the  daemon  side  allow  them. The default is for all modules to be read
              only.
```

So set up your rsync daemon with a module for the directory you want to share, but make it read only. More details [here](http://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyncd.conf).